# In prometheus query, why initial rise shown with aggregator sum is not shown by the increase function?

Tags: promql

This is observed with all rate family functions for initial rise (for few selections in operation label). We have tried using different interval, steps (setting min step to different values 4x+1 of scrape interval). Ideally __rate_interval should do all these adjustments.
[image]
[image]
The same query without any aggregation later added inspired by question from @markalex.
[image]

Comment: Is it shown without any aggregation? Also, I'm not sure if `$__rate_interval` is really meant for `increase`.

Comment: $__rate_interval is evaluated to max( $__interval + Scrape interval, 4 * Scrape interval) by grafana before it sends query to prometheus. $__rate_interval is safe to use with rate family functions (rate, irate, increase). However for testing we tried with different intervals like integers, $__interval, etc (same result) (also with different min step setting).

Comment: Yes, but if you use `increase(mymetric[$__rate_interval])`, displayed values will change with change of dashboard time range.

Comment: @markalex Why are you asking to check without aggregation. are you suspecting anything there?

Comment: To localize the problem. It is theoretically possible that `sum` has sum influence here. On the other hand it is possible that there is something going on with underlying metrics in the "beginning of time": it is easier notice something like this without aggregation.

Comment: @markalex I guess thats the issue. Credit goes to you and Sanjay (my collegue) (both asked me to do the same). I will let you explain the answer, however will update the question with a screenshot using no aggregations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see on your last screenshot misunderstanding is caused by the fact, that number of metrics being summed changed after first time tick.

Since you aggregating increases of individual metrics, and non of them actually increased, you don't see it on the second screenshot.

You might want to use `increase(sum by ... )` instead, but I **strongly recommend not to**! It's [advised](https://www.robustperception.io/rate-then-sum-never-sum-then-rate/) to use `rate`-family functions before summing, so that counter resets could be handled by `rate` (or in our case `increase`) correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to capture this. Its sometimes important, lets say the metric reports total errors and want to get alerted even it is for first time. Also if you look at it from different prespective there is increase. Actually here total requests increased however individual vectors separated by instance label did not.

Comment: @SudhakarMNSR, you still technically **can** use increase after sum, just remember that this can result in some troubles near counter resets.